# How to press android Back, Home, and Enter buttons using AndroidViewClient

Tags: android, androidviewclient

I am using [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to automate testing of my android application. I need to press android device buttons like 'Home', 'Back', and 'Enter'. How Can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function I wrote for pressing the <kbd>BACK</kbd> key:

```
def back(self):
    self.shell('input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK')
```

In the same way use `keyevent` `KEYCODE_HOME` and `keyevent` `KEYCODE_ENTER` for <kbd>HOME</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keys.
I put those functions directly into `adbclient.py` file but you can also define them in your code file as external methods.

Comment: Thanks Eliyahu, It worked well, but when I put a method in adbclient.py and call it, it says that this attribute is not defined for adbclient!!

Comment: Where and how did you put this method into `adbclient`? It should be defined inside the class there. For example put it directly after  `def type(self, text):
        self.shell(u'input text "%s"' % text)` there

Comment: You should do more efforts to solve your problems. The code above appears here on StackOverflow just 3-4 questions before when sorting with AndroidViewClient tag. Where and how to put a method into a class is a basic issue when learning Python...

Comment: I put the method in correct place, but it dosen't work. after that, I copy&paste one of it's own methods and change it to your 'back' method and I see it's worked.

Comment: I guess the problem is somewhere in your copy & paste. Anyway you can copy some original method, paste it 3 times and edit it to all 3 actions you need...